# Massive lookup in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having difficulties creating the right Excel formula for this task I'm trying to accomplish.

Sheet1
[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2
[image: Sheet2]

Sheet3[Sheet3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsigj.png)

Picture 3 should illustrate a simplified version of my problem. As you can see the problem is that eventough that the stock price of YARA should begin at 30-04-2004 it begins at 31-01-2002 just like Ericsson.

I have 600 stock prices listed as shown in picture 2. I want to list them as shown in picture 1 with the date horizontal and with one common row which has all dates. For example: The price of Ericsson LM-B SHS which is listed vertically in picture 2 B7:B199. I want it to be shown in B5 and then horizontal accordingly.

I have tried several Index Match functions but can't seem to get it right since I have this huge array as shown in picture 2 and i want to extract the different stock prices out of the 600 different columns. I have also tried to use a function like this, but without any luck:

```
=VLOOKUP(B$2;'Data'!$4:$199;MATCH(Indeks!$A3;'Data'!$5:$5;0)+1;FALSE).
```

Indeks and Data just refers to my sheets (sheetname).

Comment: Could you put together a simpler version of this problem with some sample data and example results? That way we can replicate the problem much more easily. While the screenshots help, they are not easy to work with. Sometimes, in putting together a simplified version of the problem, you find the answer yourself!

Comment: I have tried to simply my problem with the added photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following source table named *source*[image: source table]

You can get this result:

[image: result table]

With this formula (taken from cell `B1` in the result table:

`=VLOOKUP(B$1;INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;MATCH($A2;source!$A$1:$IV$1;0);1;1;"source")&":"&ADDRESS(999;MATCH($A2;source!$A$1:$IV$1;0)+1));2;0)`

**Explained step by step** from inside to outside:

[`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-E8DFFD45-C762-47D6-BF89-533F4A37673A)`($A2;source!$A$1:$IV$1;0)` returns the integer column number where `$A2`, the stock's name, is found in the source

[`ADDRESS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-D0C26C0D-3991-446B-8DE4-AB46431D4F89)`(1;MATCH(...);1;1;"source")` returns an address string like `"source!$B$1"` , the upper left corner of the lookup-area.

`ADDRESS(999;MATCH(...)+1)` similarly returns the lower right. This withaout table name, so for example `"$C$999"`

`ADRESS(...)&":"&ADDRESS(...)` concatenates both addresses to `"source!$B$1:$C$999"`

[`INDIRECT(...)`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474B3A3A-8A26-4F44-B491-92B6306FA261) turns the string to a reference on the area.

[`VLOOKUP(...)`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) finally searches your target date in this area and returns the value of the area's 2nd column.

Comment: When ever I click enter after I have entered the formula excel opens a window says: "Update Values: source" and I have to click on an excel file. Otherwise the cell just reports "#NA".

Comment: You have to change every occurence of `source` to `whatever-your-source-table-is-named`. Also increase the `999` if you've got more rows than that.